# Create a columns in MySQL table from a text/Excel/CSV

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, import, multiple-columns

I have to create a table with 920 columns, each with different varchar name. Is there a way to to it automatically from the list and in which format it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Excel fill handle](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-HP001216366.aspx) to "smart" create your query.

If you have an Excel sheet like this

```
--------------------------
| A |    B    |     C
--------------------------
| 1 | column1 | 
| 2 | column2 |
| 3 | column3 |
```

you can write on cell C1 this formula

```
=B1 & " VARCHAR(100),"
```

and then use `fill handle` to populate this for all lines (all fields name)

Copy all data from C column and add `CREATE TABLE tablename (` at the begining and remove the last comma and add a closing parenthesis `)`.

Also you need to add primary key, etc.

Thats it!

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer, but Im trying create a table in mysql database, it seems to me that this is used for Exel formating.